# .htaccess redirect only for homepage?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, homepage

My website has more languages and I want to do this redirect for every languages for example: /es/ to /es, simple with *Redirect* but this method make problems for subpages, how can I tell htaccess to use this rule only for homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the homepage is the page url: `index.php`, you'd use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(en|es|de|hi|jp|zh|...)/(index\.php)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

---

If you do not want to use `mod_rewrite` and would prefer a `mod_alias` solution, try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/(en|es|de|hi|jp|zh|...)/(index\.php)?$" /$1
```

Please note that I'm not much familiar with `mod_alias`, so the latter might not work right away. If so, do inform me with a comment here along with the request line from apache's `access_log`.